# I accidentally left the brown sugar out of my caramel sauce

Tags: food-safety

I made “caramel” popcorn crunch which called for butter, brown sugar, light corn syrup, vanilla and baking soda.

I cooked it to the soft boil stage then coated the popcorn and cereal mixture and baked at 250 for 1 hour.   Tasted a little more buttery than usual but otherwise was good.  This morning I realized I forgot to add the brown sugar!!

Will having left out the sugar impact anything other than the taste?   I give this as part of my Christmas goodie package every year and don’t want it to go bad or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the proportions of the ingredients?

Comment: My concern is that the sauce won't get "hard" enough for you to bag up the popcorn after coating it.  I'd think that without the sugar it would be likely to stay soft, but I don't have direct experience in that.

Comment: If it did get hard enough, you should be fine.